# Error Occurred in apple silicon chip while integrating firebase with flutter ,Some one can help me to clear this error

Tags: firebase, flutter, cocoa

```
Xcode build done.                                            4.8s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    objc[15838]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x207666c10) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x113fe82b8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[15838]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x207666c60) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x113fe8308). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Analyzing workspace
    note: Constructing build description
    note: Build preparation complete
3
    /Users/jp/flutterProjects/flutter_authen_mac/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:3:1: error: could not find included file 'Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig' in search paths
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you tell us what version of cocoapods is installed (pod --version) and also what verison of Firebase you have? Including your podfile may help as well. Be sure to include that info in the *question*